# title="" not displaying in html email

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email

```
<a href="http://link" target="_blank" title="Check out our NEW E-Catalogue" alt="Check out our NEW E-Catalogue" name="Check out our NEW E-Catalogue"><img alt="Check out our NEW E-Catalogue" title="Check out our NEW E-Catalogue" src="http:/image" border="0px"></a>
```

The code above is what I'm using in a HTML email, sent via a email marketing platform.

When hovering over this image in Outlook 2010, and other email clients, the link shows instead of the title text.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't control this. They do that to help stop phishing attempts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's [typical behavior](http://blog.mailchimp.com/html-email-for-the-visually-impaired/) to avoid concealing intended link targets. A snippet from the referenced link:

> **If you code an image that also links to a web page, some email apps (Outlook2000 and Apple Mail) override both the ALT and TITLE, and show the URL of the link instead.** They do this for security, so you see where the link takes you before you click.

FWIW, [as an end-user] I'd rather see where a link is going than what the author felt was more appropriate than the link itself. Case in point:

```
<a href="http://facebouk.com/login.php" title="http://facebook.com/login.php">
  Login to facebook
</a>
```